# É possivel guardar os dados de uma search?

Tags: php, mysql

Eu estou a tentar fazer um codigo em que vá pesquizar o código postal na database e traga a localização, mas não estou conseguindo!
o código é o seguinte:

```
$searchErr = '';

$employee_details='';

if(isset($_POST['save']))

{

if(!empty($_POST['Cod_Postal']))

{

    $search = $_POST['Cod_Postal'];

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("select * from localidades where Cod_Postal like '%$search%' or 




   localidade like '%$search%'");

    $stmt->execute();
    $employee_details = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print_r($employee_details);
     
}
else
{
    $searchErr = "Please enter the information";
}

}
```

...

```
<div class="input-group">
        <img class="input-icon" src="../imgs/user.png">
        <input <?php if(isset($erro_geral)) {echo 'class="erro-input"';}?> id="myFunction" 
name="Cod_Postal" type="text" placeholder="Código-Postal" <?php 
if(isset($_POST['Cod_Postal'])){echo "value='".$_POST['Cod_Postal']."'";}?> >
```

...

```
 <?php

            
             if(!$employee_details)
             {
                echo '<tr>No data found</tr>';
             }
             else{
                foreach($employee_details as $key=>$value)
                {
                    ?>
                <tr>

                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                     
                    <?php 
                }
                 
             }


            ?>
   <div class="col-sm-2">

          <button type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Submit</button>
        </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <p>Localidade:<?php echo $value['localidade'];;?> </p>

        
    </div>
```

eu queria guardar a variavél $value['localidade'];

Comment: *"mas não estou conseguindo"* e o que isso quer dizer? dá erro, não retorna dados? já fez debug para entender descobrir algum problema no código?

Answer (score -2):

Sua questão não mostra por que "não está conseguindo". Mas seja o que for, da forma que está, seu search mostrará somente o ultimo resultado do foreach.

Experimente fazer assim para ver todos os resultados:

```
foreach($employee_details as $key=>$value){ echo '<tr><td>'.$value.'</td></tr>'; }
```

Suas respostas estarão dentro da variável $value em cada volta do loop. Basta guardar (Seja lá como desejar fazer isso) a informação, na instância (volta do loop do foreach) desejada.

Comment: tem umas pessoas que parecem negativar, por simples concorrência. Sem dar explicações, derrubam a imagem do StackOverflow brasileiro. Por isso, uso mais o em inglês.